# How to get the ID of an LI with the ID of the previous LI with jquery

Tags: jquery, children

I was wondering if anyone knows if its possible to get what the ID of the next LI is with only using the ID of the previous LI.

For example

So i would want to be able to go
function getNextLI(currentliID){
    $(li#currentliID:next-child).animate({
       opacity: 1
    });
}

All the LI id's won't be in order as they are the item ids coming from the mysql database.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) method of jQuery. For example:

```
<ul>
    <li>...</li>
    <li id-"test">...</li>
    <li>NEXT</li>
    <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

The following will get you the `li` containing the word "NEXT":

```
var nextSibling = $("li#test").next();
```

Answer (score 1):

This will fix your problem:

```
var getNextLI = function(id) {
  return $('li#' + id).next('li');
};

var anaimateNext = function(id) {
  getNextLI(id).animate({ opacity: 1});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jQuery(this).next()`

```
<ol>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        <li>Item 4</li>
        <li>Item 5</li>
</ol>


jQuery(function(){

    jQuery('ol li').bind('click',function(){
        jQuery('ol li').css("background-color","#ffffff");
        jQuery(this).next().css("background-color","red");
    });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BzFfM/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
```

jQuery(function(){

jQuery('ol li').bind('click',function(){

var s = jQuery(this).next().attr("id");

});

});